# Is there a way to compare two arrays based on user input in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

MATLAB software

```
i=[0 1.264241 1.729329 1.900426 1.963369 1.986524 1.995042 1.998176 1.999329 1.999753 1.999909];
t=[0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1 1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8 2];
```

How can I call the value of i if the user input is from the t array as the position for both array is the same?

For example, if I call the value 0.2 the program will call the value 1.264341 from array i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [input](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) to get the user to enter a number, and [ismembertol](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismembertol.html) to find the number's index in `t`. Once you have the index, you can get the corresponding value in `i`. You could even throw an error if the number entered is not found in `t`. Here's an example:

```
i=[0 1.264241 1.729329 1.900426 1.963369 1.986524 1.995042 1.998176 1.999329 1.999753 1.999909];
t=[0 0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1 1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8 2];
x = input('Enter number:\n');
[~,ind] = ismembertol(x,t);
if ind > 0
  fprintf('Corresponding number in i is %g\n', i(ind))
else
  error('Number not found in i')
end
```